# Proof of $\operatorname{im}(T) = \operatorname{im}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

There is a theorem that states that if you let $T(x) = Ax$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then:

- $\ker(T) = \ker(A)$ and they are a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
- $\operatorname{im}(T) = \operatorname{im}(A)$ and they are a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I need to prove the second statement and I have been thinking and looking for it without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Il leave to you showing that Im(T)=Im(A).

Let T be the linear transformation from a finite vector space $\mathbb R^{m}$ i.e. $ T: \mathbb R^{m} \to \mathbb R^{n} $

Clearly Im(T) $\subseteq \mathbb R^{n} $

Now let $ u,v $ be vectors in $\mathbb R^{n} $, then there exists   $u',v'$ in X such that T(u')=u and T(v')=v  then we need to show that the zero vector is contained in Im(T) and that ImT is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.

By properties of linear transformations we know $T(\bar0)=\bar0$ so $\bar0$ is in the image.

T is also a linear transformation from a vector space, $ \mathbb R^{m}$. so we know $au'+bv'$ is in $ \mathbb R^{m} $ ( where a and b are real numbers).

So $T(au'+bv')=aT(u')+bT(v')=au+bv$ ( by properties of T being a linear transformation).

Thus we have shown that au+bv is in the Image of T as well and the proof is complete.